# Unable to display data in jqGrid when loading colModel & colName dynamically

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have use jqGrid to display data. In my current grid all columns are dynamic. It is coming from a web service.
I have called $.ajax call to get the colNames and colModels after that I set colNames and colModel to jqGrid.

I found that grid shows empty rows (no data except row number), pages is showing correctly. But it does not show data.

[image]

Here is my service side code.

```html
 [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json), WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public code.jqGridColumns GetColumnForSQLQuery()
        {
            System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection QueryString = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString;
            string Sql = String.Empty;
            string dbName = String.Empty;
            if (QueryString.Count > 0)
            {
                Sql = QueryString["Sql"].ToString();
                dbName = QueryString["dbName"].ToString();
            }
            if (Sql.Contains("where"))
                Sql = Sql + " and 1=2";
            else
                Sql = Sql + " where 1=2";

            string connectionString = "data source = " + General.DBServer + "; initial catalog=" + dbName + ";Integrated security=false;User ID=" + General.SqlUserName + "; password=" + General.SqlPassword;
            databaseDataContext db = new databaseDataContext(connectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Sql, db.Connection as SqlConnection);
            if (cmd.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                cmd.Connection.Open();
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            DataSet dSet = null;
                dSet = new DataSet();
                dSet.Load((IDataReader)dReader, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges, "data");
            dReader.Close();
            dReader.Dispose();
            DataTable dTable = new DataTable("Columns");
            dTable.Columns.Add("ColumnName");
            dTable.Columns.Add("Caption");
            code.jqMetaData meta = new jqMetaData();
            foreach (DataColumn column in dSet.Tables[0].Columns)
            {
                meta.ColModels.Add(new ColModel(column.ColumnName, column.ColumnName));
                meta.ColNames.Add(new ColName(column.ColumnName)); 
            }
            code.jqGridColumns jqMetaData = new jqGridColumns();
            jqMetaData.jqColNames = meta.GetColNames();
            jqMetaData.jqColModels = meta.GetColModels();
            return jqMetaData;
        }
```

As per my skills in jqGrid, it returns data correctly.

Here is my JavaScript snippet.

```html
 var colM = [];// '[' + data.d.jqColModels + ']';
            var colN = [];//'[' + data.d.jqColNames + ']';
            colM = data.d.jqColModels.split('INECOM');
            colN = data.d.jqColNames.split('INECOM');
            var ServiceUrl = $.session.get("ClientURL") + '/GetDataBySqlQuery?dbName=' + $.session.get('dbName') + "&Sql=" + FMS;
            $("#uxData").jqGrid({
                url: ServiceUrl,
                datatype: 'xml',
                mtype: 'GET',
                colNames: colN,//['CardCode']//
                colModel: colM,//[{name:'CardCode',index:'CardCode'}], //
                loadError: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    $(this).HideBusy();
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                }
       ...
       ...
});
```

For extra information I am attaching some more screen shot to get clear idea.
[image]

After more investigation on jqGrid, I observed that jqGrid parse these models and prepare ,I also observed that does something which I don't understand but I am sure it extract information from colModel and make it name:'somevalue', index:'somevalue' sort of...

Is there any mess with my data returning from web service?

FYI

[image]

Comment: First of all you should **always** include the version of jqGrid which you use if you report some problem. Seconds you should use Fiddler or Developer Tools to make HTTP trace and to include JSON response as the string. In the case one will clear see which the server return and one can easy reproduce the problem. The images which you post looks like you returns `colModel` in a wrong way. It should be **object** instead of strange strings like `"{name:'CardCode',index:'CardCode'}"`. The existence of `'` instead of `"` show additionally that you use wrong encodding. of `colModel`

Comment: Thanks for your support, You are correct there is some issue with server side, it is returning as string instead of object. I make some changes in web service and tweak in js which make it workable.

Comment: This is the [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1833859.aspx?Create+colNames+colModel+for+jqGrid+using+C+) helps me resolve this issue.

Comment: I am new to all these stuff and force to make it workable in real time application, Fiddler app is also new to me. Will try to learn more... Journey is too long. HATS OFF TO YOU OLEG

Comment: You are welcome! I'm glad to hear that your problem is solved now and I could help you in some way. Best wishes!

Comment: Thanks Oleg, Without your support / suggestion I could not be able to track down the issue. In my earlier posts also, you help me to point out those issues. Once again Thanks... Looking forward to your support in future...